# CC2541 Interface with ST7789V based 1.14" TFT Display

Tags: spi, lcd, texas-instruments, tft

I am working off a custom board having CC2541 from Texas as the Main Controller and a 1.14" TFT Display being controlled via ST7789V Drive IC. These two are connected over the SPI Interface. However, I am not able to generate results on the display. The LCD would sometimes glitch when instructions are being passed but it will not print anything. The LCD in use works on 4-line 8-bit Serial Mode.

Can anyone help me point out where I might be going wrong. I am attaching a screenshot of my schematic. I have been trying some example codes up till now from here and there and studying things. It seems the CC2541 has some limitations in:

- The SPI operating frequency goes to a max of 8MHz (from datasheet)
- The RAM of CC2541 is very low

Given these observations, can the LCD be interfaced with the controller in question? Is there any additional approach that needs to be taken? I am positive my controller SPI is working fine through reading from an oscilloscope but the LCD doesn't display anything.

[image: Custom Schematic for LCD Module connected to CC2541]

Below is the code I'm using for configuring SPI

```
#define SPI_BAUD_M  0
#define SPI_BAUD_E  16


void initSPI()

{
    // Configure USART1 for Alternative 1 => Port P1
    PERCFG = (PERCFG | 0x02);

// Set pins 2, 3 and 5 as peripheral I/O and pin 4 as GPIO output.
P1SEL = (P1SEL & ~BIT4) | BIT5 | BIT6 | BIT7;
P1DIR |= BIT4;

    
 * Configure SPI
 */

// Set USART to SPI mode and Master mode.
U1CSR &= ~(U1MODE | U1SLAVE);

// Set:
// - mantissa value
// - exponent value
// - clock phase to be centered on first edge of SCK period
// - negative clock polarity (SCK low when idle)
// - bit order for transfers to LSB first
U1BAUD = SPI_BAUD_M;
U1GCR = (U1GCR & ~(U0GCR_BAUD_E | U0GCR_CPOL | U0GCR_CPHA | U0GCR_ORDER))
    | SPI_BAUD_E;
    
}
```

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing any code how you interface with the display. How do you control RST, RS and CS? How do you send bytes over SPI? How is the SPI mode configured, CPOL and CPHA?

Comment: Adding all this and other relevant info in the question.

Comment: I have't got the slightest clue if SPI polarity and phase are correct for the display (I hope you know) but sending LSB first is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Justme I am using SPI Mode 0 i.e CPOL = 0 and CPHA = 0;

Comment: There's a slight confusion, I do agree that the MSBFIRST is the right one, however, reading from the ST7789 datasheet, it appears that the Clock is LOW when it is idle i.e CPOL = 0. However, some libraries such as the one referenced are using SPI Mode 3 which means CPOL = 1 and CPHA = 1;

https://github.com/cbm80amiga/Arduino_ST7789_Fast

Comment: The phase and polarity bits are not identical between manufacturers and their values must not be assumed. You need to look at which polarity and phase settings of your MCU result in a bus waveform that matches what the display needs.

Comment: @Justme Ok so I was able to follow your suggestion getting the display to work on SPI Mode 3, however, the complete screen is not getting filled and some parts on the end are glitchy. The resolution I'm using is 240 x 240. Whereas, the resolution of the display is 135 x 240. Any suggestions? Do you this could be because of the MCU operating at 2MHz instead of 8Mhz as required by LCD?